# How to resolve the issue in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am working on Jenkins by following below link and I am new to working on Jenkins.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/05/27/continuous-deploymentdelivery-with-jenkins-and-vs-team-services/

Here I am facing the issue when I am installing the Jenkins its redirect to localhost URL and displaying the web page is like below figure and I am   downloading the Jenkins from the below link. after redirect that its shows the Jenkins login and here I am informing before that I am not set the any logging details at any where in the Jenkins.
https://jenkins.io/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, default "admin" user password is available in **/var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword** file.

I am not 100% sure about windows, you can check if **secrets\initialAdminPassword** file is available in **Jenkins install directory**. If yes, then try to login with credentials mentioned in this file